# Directory path to open a file in c program

Tags: files, c

I am trying to append data to a text file (info.txt) at the home directory using C programming language. I am supposed to use the function fopen() that has the following syntax fopen("file path"."a"). When I run the piece of code I get Error opening the file.  This means the  file pointer assigned to fopen() function is NULL. I am guessing that the file path I am using is not correct. I used /home/maverick/info.txt  where maverick is my user name. Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

FILE *fptr;

int main()
{
fptr= fopen("/home/maverick/info.txt","a");

if(fptr==0)

{

printf("Error opening the file!");

exit(1);

}

fprintf(fptr, "\n More Books to come");

fclose(fptr);

return(0);

}
```

I tried to look for the correct command for the path of files at home directory but could not look it up. If someone is experienced with C programming in Ubuntu could solve this issue, I will be grateful.

Comment: Why are you using `"info.txt/home/maverick"` as the file path name?

Comment: The text file is info.txt and my user name is maverick, can you suggest something else?

Comment: Why not `"/home/maverick/info.txt"`?

Comment: I clicked right click at info.txt to check for the path and found /home/maverick as the parent folder

Comment: I did that "/home/maverick/info.txt" but in this case the program did not compile at all

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the extra information (compile-time error messages, etc.) there.

Comment: @Derhham just replacing one string with another could not make the program to stop compiling, unless you made another error as well. Check carefully once again if your statement is `fptr= fopen("/home/maverick/info.txt","a");`

Comment: I meant the terminal gave me the user name line that has $ at its right end not a compilation problem. I was supposed to get the program running normally. This what I got in my terminal (maverick@maverick-Inspiron-3581:~$ gcc -o hello chapter28ex3.c  ) , in the following line ((maverick@maverick-Inspiron-3581:~$ ./hello) and finally the same line again ((maverick@maverick-Inspiron-3581:~$ )

Comment: @Derhham So program probably compiled correctly. Run it.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `fopen("file path","a")` means that you have to substitute **full pathname to the file you want to open** for `file path`. In your case the pathname is `/home/maverick/info.txt` so your function call should be `fopen("/home/maverick/info.txt","a")`.

Comment: You can also use ***relative*** path names, just as you use them in command lines.

Comment: @FedKad Yes you can, but in that case the behavior of the program will be different depending on what directory is the current directory when you run it. For pathnames hardcoded in the program (as in this case), this isn't a good idea.

Comment: I meant the terminal gave me the user name line that has $ at its right end not a compilation problem. I was supposed to get the program running normally. This what I got in my terminal (maverick@maverick-Inspiron-3581:~$ gcc -o hello chapter28ex3.c ) , in the following line ((maverick@maverick-Inspiron-3581:~$ ./hello) and finally the same line again ((maverick@maverick-Inspiron-3581:~$ ) –

Comment: @Derhham on successful compilation, the compiler does not produce any output. Your program also does not produce any output if there is no error. Check your `info.txt` file if the program has written the text to the file.

Comment: It did ;))), thanks raj I really appreciate your help